# node curl error "Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT"

Tags: node.js, curl

I get a JWT token after authenticating on an API with a POST req.

With that token, I can make a successful `curl` call from my command prompt:

`curl --request GET https://corpURL/customer/wlsAccountManagement/v1/billingAccount/23435657 --header "env: it04" --header "Authorization: Bearer tokenstring..."`

But when I try to exec this in node, it fails with `Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT`.

I even tried a basic curl in the command prompt and it works:

`curl -v https://corpURL/customer/wlsAccountManagement/v1/billingAccount/23435657`

It just tells me I am unauthorized `{"message":"Unauthorized"}`, which is correct.

In node, I can't even get the `{"message":"Unauthorized"}`, it still gives me `Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT`.

The reason I'm using curl is because I can see more info. Using `axios` it gives me a `"socket hang up"` error.

I have been trying to get this to work and searching online for a solution for over a day. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Why does it work in the command prompt but not in node? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a bug on a backend. Do you have access to more detailed logs from server?

Comment: The backend API? Or the backend I'm making? There is nothing in mine but the token call and then the GET request for data which is the issue. The corp API for the GET request is solid, it works, curl in terminal proves it works, and another team has an old node project where they use an axios.get() request and it works. I don't get why my simple request doesn't though and why curl doesn't either. Thanks!

Comment: In your working curl example you set header „env” to “it04”. Are you setting it in your node call? Maybe lack of it induces some erroneous  behavior in corp API?

Comment: Yes, `const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    env: 'it04',
  };`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who can't get an exec with curl to work in node, or using the packages axios or request, use the https package in node like so:

```
const options = {
    hostname: 'hostDomain', // no https protocol
    port: 443,
    path: '/path/to/get',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer tokenString`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  const req = https.request(options, response => {
    response.on('data', d => {
      process.stdout.write(d);
    });
  });

  req.on('error', e => {
    console.error(e);
  });

  req.end();
```

This was the only way I was able to get the response so far, in node. I may tweak the structure as it doesn't seem that clean, but it works! You may also need to set the env var for your cert file `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=cert.pem` as I already had. Peace.

*EDIT*

I found a solution with axios, you need to create instances with a baseURL like the https request has it:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://corpURL',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      env: 'it04',
    },
  });

  axiosInstance
    .get('/get/path')
    .then(response => console.log('response', response.data))
    .catch(err => console.log('err', err));
```